# Does doxygen's command have no long options?

Tags: doxygen

`doxyen -h` has only "short options".

"long options" is not there at all?

how to know the meaning of abbreviation?

For example, the meaning of `g` in `doxyen -g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does doxyen's command have no long options?

None are mentioned in the manpage, but the documentation site mentions `--version` and `--help`. I checked the source code; These are the only two long options.

> how to know the meaning of abbreviation?

The options are listed and their meanings are described in the documentation.

> For example, the meaning of 'g' in `doxyen -g`.

Documentation says:

> 1. Use doxygen to generate a template configuration file:
>    `doxygen [-s] -g [configName]`

Comment: Not completely true. The first line of the chapter for the doxygen usage (https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/doxygen_usage.html) says: " Calling doxygen with the --help option at the command line" and in the Troubleshooting  chapter (use doxygen --version if you are), but in general correct the other startup options don't have a long version.

Comment: @albert Edited accordingly. I also found `--version` mentioned